# Wrong Count when condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to count some rows when multiple conditions are met. Everything works fine, but I get a wrong count. Working with arrays is painful for me (still trying to improve). Below you can find the code I have, also I have this [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FoHkogaCMpozdRsVdErMNbQTaTgZaG5DORO_4kGHKl8/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function countD() 
{ 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FoHkogaCMpozdRsVdErMNbQTaTgZaG5DORO_4kGHKl8');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Response Data');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var td = Utilities.formatDate(subDaysFromDate(new Date(),1), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var mbs = 0;
  var cities = getCity();
  sh.getRange(2, 19, cities.length, 1).setValues(cities);
//  Logger.log(cities);
  for (var j=1;j<vA.length;j++)
  {

    var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[j][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
      if(vA[j][2]=="ABC1" && d==td && vA[j][10]=="Appointment booked" &&  vA[j][17]=='London') 
       Logger.log(vA[j][10]);
      {
        mbs++;
      }
      Logger.log(mbs)
  return mbs;
    }

    }
```

It returns every time value 1. I also have two other functions inside this script. `getCity()` which extract city from column L and `subDaysFromDate()` which get today date and subtract n days. You can find both scripts if you open script file from the sample.

Thank you!

Comment: You are starting the first for-loop at index 1, instead of 0. Arrays are 0 based index in javascript

Comment: Theres an unneccessary block statement in your code, i think its meant to be part of the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple problems:

1) Your loop is starting at j=1. Arrays in javascript start at index zero, so you're probably meant to start at j=0. If you were intentionally skipping j=0, then nevermind.

2) the `return mbs;` statement is inside the for loop, so the for loop will execute exactly one time, and then countD returns

3) After you do the `if(vA[j][2]=="ABC1" && d==td && vA[j][10]=="Appointment booked" &&  vA[j][17]=='London')` check, you immediately have a logger.log statement which is *not* inside of curly braces. Doing this means that one statement -- the log statement -- is the entirety of what will be executed if the condition is true. The part that comes afterwards, the `{ mbs++; }`, is completely unrelated to the if statement and will always run.

So here's the fixed code:

```
function countD() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FoHkogaCMpozdRsVdErMNbQTaTgZaG5DORO_4kGHKl8');
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Response Data');
    var rg = sh.getDataRange();
    var vA = rg.getValues();
    var td = Utilities.formatDate(subDaysFromDate(new Date(), 1), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var mbs = 0;
    var cities = getCity();
    sh.getRange(2, 19, cities.length, 1).setValues(cities);
    //  Logger.log(cities);

    for (var j = 0; j < vA.length; j++) {
        var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[j][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
        if (vA[j][2] == "ABC1" && d == td && vA[j][10] == "Appointment booked" && vA[j][17] == 'London') {
            Logger.log(vA[j][10]); 
            mbs++;
        }
        Logger.log(mbs)
    }
    return mbs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(vA[j][2]=="ABC1" && d==td && vA[j][10]=="Appointment booked" &&  vA[j][17]=='London') 
   Logger.log(vA[j][10]);
  {
    mbs++;
  }
```

the upper code logs only if the if condition is true. `mbs++` however is *always* executed ( the wrapping `{ }` are useless). You may wanted to do this:

```
if(vA[j][2]=="ABC1" && d==td && vA[j][10]=="Appointment booked" &&  vA[j][17]=='London')       
  {
    mbs++;
    Logger.log(vA[j][10]);
  }
```

And you *return* inside the loop, that probably should be outside ( so that it returns *after* the loop, not after the *first looping*).

Answer (score 0):

You are unconditionally returning mbs in your for loop. Your loop only ever runs once.

mbs will also always have the value of 1, because this block is not actually effected by your if statement:

```
{
    mbs++;
}
```

The line where you log is what will be affected by your condition, the code in the block above will run unconditionally.

In conclusion, I think this is what you want to achieve (I haven't tested this, you might have additional bugs):

```
function countD() { 
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FoHkogaCMpozdRsVdErMNbQTaTgZaG5DORO_4kGHKl8');
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Response Data');
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var td = Utilities.formatDate(subDaysFromDate(new Date(),1), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var mbs = 0;
    var cities = getCity();
    sh.getRange(2, 19, cities.length, 1).setValues(cities);
    for (var j=1;j<vA.length;j++) {

        var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[j][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
        if(vA[j][2]=="ABC1" && d==td && vA[j][10]=="Appointment booked" &&  vA[j][17]=='London') 
        {
            Logger.log(vA[j][10]);
            mbs++;
        }
        Logger.log(mbs)

    }
    return mbs;
}
```